# Не удается включить сжатие текста для файла js

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

**Параметры конфига nginx**

```
 server {
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        ....
        location / {
            location ~* ^.+\.(webp|css|js|woff2|svg|png|ico)$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
                expires modified +1w;
            }
            location / {
                try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
            }
        }
    }
```

pagespeed показывать один единственный файл для которого не работает сжатие текста - .js
Кэш работает, а вот сжатие js нет. В чем дело?

Comment: А это настоящий файл или он из `@fallback` прилетает?

Comment: Не силен в настройках. Что значит из @fallback прилетает? Он лежит на сайте, в html документе его подключаю по принципу <script src="/tpl/js/js.js" rel="preload" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>